# Are there LEGO sets designed for adults?

Tags: sets, design

Other than the LEGO Architecture sets are there any other sets or series that were designed principally for an adult audience?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there's any LEGO set for which the age target goes any further than 16+.

Within the 16+ range, you'll find several sets, mostly in the exclusive sets (series 10xxx): mainly modular houses and some Star Wars UCS sets. Usually these are sets with a high parts count and a price to match.

There's a functionality to filter sets by age on [shop.lego.com](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/ByAge-12), but it doesn't seem to work properly. Neither Brickset or Bricklink appear to offer such a functionality (yet).

Comment: Yeah, the problem with the filter is that it's aimed at filtering out sets that are too complicated for young kids.  So you set the filter for 14+, and it shows you all the sets that a person 14+ could build: all of them.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work that way, I hadn't noticed that. Makes you wonder what the point of specifying the minimum age, then.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2020 there is now an entire [range of "18+" sets](https://brickset.com/sets/tag-18-Plus) targeted at adults. 35 sets by the time of this answer. LEGO has even went to create a [web page](https://lego.com/adults) dedicated to adults promoting these sets.