# Looking for Adult LEGO

Tags: afol

> Possible duplicate of:
>
> [Are there LEGO sets designed for adults?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/are-there-lego-sets-designed-for-adults)

The pieces are smaller for higher resolution, the colors are not primary and there are more of them.

Does this exist? I had in mind the standard 4 by 2 brick becomes 8 bricks each with 4 by 2 pegs.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" explicitly excludes LEGO Architecture while this question is open-ended.

Comment: you might also want to check out the [Technic](http://www.lego.com/en-us/technic) line of LEGOs which are more challenging than the typical brick-focused sets you are probably familiar with.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes.** LEGO® may still be a toy, but it clearly a toy for all ages.  Here are two examples:

## LEGO Architecture

LEGO Architecture is clearly aimed at adults.

[image: LEGO Architecture example]

From one of LEGO's press releases:

> With models developed in collaboration with architects, LEGO Architecture inspires future architects, engineers and designers as well as architecture fans around the world using the LEGO brick as a medium for reproducing esteemed structures. Fans of all ages can collect and construct iconic architectural sites, including: Frank Lloyd Wright’s Guggenheim Museum and Fallingwater, the Space Needle in Seattle, the Willis Tower and John Hancock Center in Chicago, New York’s Empire State Building and Rockefeller Center, The White House in Washington, D.C., Farnsworth House in Plano, Illinois and the Burj Kalifa in Dubai. Each LEGO Architecture set contains a booklet featuring step-by-step building instructions that is prefaced by exclusive, archival history, information and photographs of each iconic building, its design origin, its architect and its architectural features.

I'm sure there are some young architects out there, but this level of depth is more typical of adults.

[image: collection]

## Serious Play

LEGO has also a corporate-focused play for adults called [LEGO® SERIOUS PLAY®](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Serious_Play)

> Build a better workshop with the LEGO® SERIOUS PLAY® program!
>
> The LEGO® SERIOUS PLAY® program is a radical and innovative process designed to enhance business performance through building with LEGO bricks.

[image: serious play starter kit]

Comment: I like the reference to LEGO Architecture (didn't include it in my answer as it was IMHO already mentioned in the other post), however, it doesn't meet the "The pieces are smaller for higher resolution, the colors are not primary and there are more of them." criteria (you could argue if tan and white are not primary, but the "there are more of them" clearly indicates the OP wants to have many more colors/shades of a given color).

Comment: I am happy to admit that I ignored the color part of the question and focused more on the adult aspect.  IMHO LEGO has done great on [embracing color diversity](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Colour_Palette) and [there is a vibrant market for pieces in all colors](http://www.bricklink.com/browseTree.asp?itemType=P).  It would be great to see more *sets* aimed at AFOL, but the LEGO Architecture series is the closest thing to that that I know of.

Comment: I am in full agreement with the last part of your statement.

Comment: Wait, what? Are those Duplo bricks in the lego "serious play" pile? And how is a minifig-sized motorcycle helmet supposed to be serious? Maybe I have no idea what i'm talking about...

Comment: @mindstormsboi Quick Google search will reveal what "LEGO Serious Play" is all about.

Answer (score 4):

LEGO has recently released a number of sets in [LEGO Art series](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-LEGO-Art). Each set is designed to create an image which consist of multiple of tiny 1x1 round plates or 1x1 tiles and has plenty of extra parts to create one of several alternative images.

Example with [Andy Warhol's Marilyn Monroe (31197)](https://brickset.com/sets/31197-1/Andy-Warhol-s-Marilyn-Monroe)

[image]

Included pieces seen above allow you to make one of 4 iconic images:

[image][image][image][image]

Same goes with [Star Wars The Sith (31200)](https://brickset.com/sets/31200-1/Star-Wars-The-Sith)

[image]

[image][image][image]

Three copies of this set allows you to create another much larger version:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you indicate yourself, the best answers regarding your question and current LEGO are already given [in the other post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/are-there-lego-sets-designed-for-adults). If you are not restricted by "current LEGO", I know of two more options:

1. You might want to look at [Nanoblocks](http://www.ohioart.com/brands/nanoblock) which, while still a children's toy, has smaller bricks and a different color pallette. I don't know much about the quality of Nanoblocks - the plastic does seem cheaper than LEGO's.

[image]

2. Another option is to look at [Modulex](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Modulex), but you cannot find new sets as this line of LEGO bricks was only produced briefly from 1963 to 1965**. It was designed for adults (more specifically: for architects) as a system to build models of existing and planned buildings. Bricks are smaller, and have a different geometry (1:1 vs 5:6 for LEGO). Buying Modulex is expensive due to the limited production run and the fact that the last Modulex was produced 50 years ago. Bricklink does have [Modulex items available](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?q=Modulex) for sale though, so you might find this something worth investigating further. There is a (not really updated) website for Modulex fans at [MiniBricksMadness](http://minibricksmadness.com).

[image: Sample Modulex House]
<sub>(source: [minibricksmadness.com](https://minibricksmadness.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/YVD_flickr_house.jpg))</sub>

---

**) Modulex continued to be produced until the early 1980s in limited quantities by Modulex A/S, as per this [article(PDF)](https://minibricksmadness.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Saving-Modulex2.pdf)

Comment: Nanoblocks are nowhere as good as LEGO. Clutch power is pretty weak and any piece bigger than 1x1 allows pieces under it to slide around.

Comment: [Pixelblocks](http://www.amazon.com/Pixelblocks-Fantasy-2000-Block-Set/dp/B000BITRVE) also fit your theme.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that the best way for adults to embrace LEGO (if you know basic coding) would to get into the Mindstorms and maybe build complex moving structures.

Comment: Doing LEGO robotics or automation is definitely an interesting area for AFOLs.  The LEGO instructions are laid out so well I'm not sure that knowing coding is a prerequisite.

Answer (score -4):

You could take a look at other non-LEGO brands targeting AFOLs. These can be more affordable, but also may be of a different quality.